# East Coaster or east coaster?

Tags: capitalization

When referring to a person or persons, do you capitalize which coast they are from? I’m editing a book and the relevant sentence includes “and the east and west coasters” - I think it’s awkward and will try to get him to change it, but still would like to know what is correct!

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143908/when-does-a-locational-distinction-change-its-suffix-and-capitialization-in-a-pr and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242399/east-coast-east-coast-or-east-coast?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you’re talking about the two coasts of the US, one reference, *The Chicago Manual of Style*, says that *East Coast* and *West Coast*, as names of regions, are to be treated as proper nouns. Thus, for them, *East Coaster* would be capitalized exactly as is, say, *New Yorker*.

Comment: Not in my book. You only capitalise if it's part of an actual name, not if it's a 'general direction'. So, the south of England or west coast, but South Shields or North Berwick.

Comment: And the fact that they are recognized regions makes East Coaster a demonym, and we capitalize those.

Comment: Hmm… I suppose if they are recognised regions - though to me they're just the bits either side of the country where the land hits the sea.

Comment: @PhilSweet - OK, means nothing to a Brit. We have a west coast & an east coast too.

Comment: *Chicago* doesn’t offer such guidance lightly. In the US, saying *the East Coast* is like saying the *Great Plains*, or in the UK,  *the Midlands*.